# remove item from object by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an item from `object` I tried `$.grep` and `delete` but none of these working. `delete` won't remove and `$.grep` return empty `object`. I want to remove `firstName` if value equal by `John`

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 50,
    eyeColor: "blue"
  },
  1: {
    firstName: "John2",
    lastName: "Doe2",
    age: 51,
    eyeColor: "blue2"
  }
};

var r = "John";

// first try

//for (var firstName in obj) {
//  if (obj[firstName] === r)
//   delete obj[firstName]
//}

// second try

//var obj = $.grep(obj, function(e) {
 // return e.firstName != r;
//});


console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I just want to remove it by value not index or etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `obj` is a collection with numeric (let's assume this just for now) indices starting by zero, incremented by one. For me that's the definition of an array. So... Why is `obj` not an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not iterating correctly. It should be:

```
for (var i in obj)
    if (obj[i].firstName == r)
        delete obj[i].firstName;
```

Note this will remove the first name property only, not John's entire object.

Comment: Thanks, it works good. And what about remove John's entire object? just `delete cart[i];` ?

Comment: @Andreas It's an object, not an array.

Comment: @tourtravel - change the last line to `delete obj[i]`;

Answer (score 0):

Try doing underscorejs

```
delete myObject.regex
```

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 0):

According to your Object structure. This is how I would've done that.

Get values of the properties. Use a `forEach` and change it.

Just in case, may be you need your `obj` afterwards

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 50,
    eyeColor: "blue"
  },
  1: {
    firstName: "John2",
    lastName: "Doe2",
    age: 51,
    eyeColor: "blue2"
  }
};
 var r = Object.values(obj);
 r.forEach(function(e){
     e.firstName === "John" ? delete e.firstName : null
     
})
console.log(r)
```